# Unconditional do-done block in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a block of `echo` statements in a Bash script that I need to pipe to the FTP command. I got that working, but I need to do it unconditionally.

So I made up a dummy `if` statement, like this:

```
if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "..."
  # ...
fi | ftp -n
```

I tried just a straight `do ... done` block without a condition, but it didn't like that (`Syntax error: got do, expecting Newline`).

So obviously, this works, but is there a way to eliminate the `if` statement and have an "anonymous" or "unconditional" `do` block in Bash? I have to pipe all the output to FTP, but only the output of that block; the rest of the script is for actual processing by my script.

Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use curly braces to delimit a block:

```
{
    echo 1...
    echo 2...
} | ftp -n
```

or, use a Here Doc:

```
cat << EOF | ftp -n
1...
2...
EOF
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was using a heredoc before, but I needed a way to dynamically build the list of subcommands, so I opted for the `echo`/pipe solution.

Comment: Note that if you put the `}` on the same line as the last command, you need to put a semicolon before it so it's not mistaken for just an argument. That is, `echo "whatever"; }` will end the block, but `echo "whatever" }` will just print "whatever }".

Answer (score 1):

You can just subshell it with `( <cmds> )`. For example:

```
(
    echo 1
    echo 2
) | sed 's/^/x/'
```

will give you:

```
x1
x2
```

You can also use `{}` instead of `()`. Normally that would result in running in the context of the current shell rather than a subshell but the fact it's in a pipeline will make that moot - `bash` runs it in a subshell anyway.

And, as an aside (though probably irrelevant for *this* question since you're seeking to remove it), your `if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]` statement could be replaced with the more succinct `if true`.

Comment: @ruakh, my quotes in the earlier comment come straight from the `bash` manpage but I *think* I see where you're coming from, that the fact the code is in a pipeline means that there's no real distinction here between `()` and `{}` - the pipeline places both into a subshell. I'll update for that but, if you mean something else, please explain further (and possibly add a citation).

Comment: Re: "the fact the code is in a pipeline means that there's no real distinction here between `()` and `{}` - the pipeline places both into a subshell": Yes, that's exactly what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are sufficient, but another workaround is to use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "open foobar.net" "user fubahr" "password whatever" "...etc" | ftp -n
```

Comment: If you need to dynamically generate the stuff to print, you can build it in an array (`toprint=("first line" "second line"; toprint+=("third line");` etc... and the print it with `printf '$s\n' "${toprint[@]}"`.

Comment: Even more succinct, but equally pointless: `if :; then`. The idiom is good for unconditional loops, though.